# How to add new item to materialize css collection?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Materialize css has collections `https://materializecss.com/collections.html`

I wonder if there is specific method to add new item on the fly to the collection or I should somehow construct html by myself using jquery for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Since a link to this was in my first search results when I looked for a similar problem, I'll answer with what I know so far.

There is no built in option/method to dynamically add list items to a collection but you can use JQuery to do this.

```js
$('.add-item').click(function() {
  $('.collection').append('<li class="collection-item">item<a href="#!" class="remove-item secondary-content"><i class="material-icons mat-red-text">remove_circle_outline</i></a></li>');
});
$('.collection').on('click', '.remove-item', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section container">
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item">
      item
      <a href="#!" class="remove-item secondary-content">
      <i class="material-icons mat-red-text">remove_circle_outline</i>
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn add-item">add</button>
</div>
```

The snippet should work, it's not complete but it should work.

What I want to point out is the use of the .on() method for the remove part. When you dynamically add elements to the DOM that have events of their own, you need to use the .on() otherwise the event will not get triggered. Simply using the remove with .click() will not work for dynamically added elements;

Specifically for materializecss, there is a small issue with the styling for the last li in the ul, you will notice an extra bottom-border. I still need to figure out how to solve that.